# SQL Server BCP: Quotes around fields but some fields contain quotes within

Tags: sql-server, mariadb, bcp, load-data-infile

`'bcp DBName..vieter out c:\test003.txt -c -T -t"\",\"" -r"\"\n\"" -S SERVER'`

The above field terminator (ie. -t"","" -r""\n"") works and gets all .csv data fields surrounded by quotation marks.

However, one of the fields in the data stores written articles which have quotes themselves. When I import the data to a database it doesn't copy perfectly because the parser is interpreting quotations within the articles as terminated fields. Is there an easy fix to this?

I tried multiple variations of options for 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY' 'ENCLOSED BY' and 'ESCAPED BY' but can't seem to get the files to import perfectly.

This is the query structure, in case you aren't familiar with it:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/myinfotel/dump_new/NewsItemImages.csv' INTO TABLE NewsItemImages FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

And here is an example record that isn't copying correctly into the database:

`"CP1000066268","BX101-1219_2016_205649.jpg","FILE - In this Monday, Dec. 19, 2016 file photo Maine Republican Gov. Paul LePage, right, and House Speaker Sara Gideon, D-Freeport, attend the Electoral College vote at the State House in Augusta, Maine. LePage says he had weight loss surgery and jokes that now "there's 50 less pounds of me to hate." The Republican revealed the bariatric surgery for the first time Wednesday, Jan. 11. He says he underwent the procedure on Sept. 29 and returned to work a day later. (AP Photo/Robert F. Bukaty)","","100","69","650","447","0","","","1","","1","0","live","2017-01-11 16:56:18.000"`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you wanting a solution in? Its not clear to me why you are referencing SQL Server and MariaDB?

Comment: Microsoft's bcp.exe Utility is horrible for exporting/importing delimited files where the field data may contain linebreaks, quotes or the delimiters themselves. If you want an RFC 4180 experience I highly recommend ditching the bcp.exe Utility and switching to another solution such as PowerShell's `Export-Csv` and `Import-Csv` cmdlets.

Comment: Shoot. bcp utility has worked fine for the other tables. It's just 2 tables (the 2 largest ones) that have trouble importing properly. I'll look into a Powershell alternative.

Comment: What is the syntax in PowerShell to connect to a remote server hostname and port no. ? Currently I'm trying: `Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "query" -ServerInstance "host,port" -Username "username" -Password "password" | Export-Csv -Path "path"`. 

No idea if this is correct

Answer (score 0):

Turns out exporting from Sql Server Management Studio was the solution (or I suppose using the sqlcmd command in the command line would also do the trick). Bizarre. I tried exporting to a `CSV` with both `bcp`, and `Excel` (it's built in Get Data function), but all to no avail.

All I did was connect to the database in SSMS, spit out the table in a query, and "Save Results As" into a .csv. Everything is parsed perfectly now. Here is a link that I used to guide me for this solution.

https://blog.devart.com/how-to-export-sql-server-data-from-table-to-a-csv-file.html